# How (in)secure are cell phones in reality?

Tags: domain-name-system, security, cellular

I was recently re-reading an [old Wired article](http://www.wired.com/techbiz/people/magazine/16-12/ff_kaminsky) about the Kaminsky DNS Vulnerability and the story behind it.

In this article there was a [quote](http://www.wired.com/techbiz/people/magazine/16-12/ff_kaminsky?currentPage=2) that came across a little bit exaggerated to me:

> "The first thing I want to say to
>   you," Vixie told Kaminsky, trying to
>   contain the flood of feeling, "is
>   never, ever repeat what you just told
>   me over a cell phone."
>
> Vixie knew how easy it was to
>   eavesdrop on a cell signal, and he had
>   heard enough to know that he was
>   facing a problem of global
>   significance. If the information were
>   intercepted by the wrong people, the
>   wired world could be held ransom.
>   Hackers could wreak havoc. Billions of
>   dollars were at stake, and Vixie
>   wasn't going to take any risks.

When reading this I could not help but feel like it was a bit blown-up and theatrical. Now, I know absolutely nothing about cell phones and the security problems involved, but to my understanding, cell phone security has quite improved over the past few years.

**So my question is: *how insecure are cell phones in reality? Are there any good articles that dig a bit deeper into this matter?***

Comment: As with most systems, a targeted attack by people who know what they're looking for generally will be successful, and in *drastically* less time than you'd think. If you are a very high risk target, you should be very paranoid. Most people aren't nearly as much a target as they'd like to think, and thus don't need to be very worried.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommmend reading this from slashdot:  [GSM Decryption Published](http://it.slashdot.org/story/09/12/28/1931256/GSM-Decryption-Published?from=rss). Following the links in the article and reading the comments.

more info at  [A5/1 Security Project aims at publicizing cryptographic weaknesses found in today's cellular networks](http://reflextor.com/trac/a51)